# How to get rid of column name comment when exporting DDL

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I have a problem with trying to export DDL from a table. I am using sqlplus to run this query:

```
SQL> SPOOL PACKAGE.PKS
SQL> SELECT TEXT FROM some_table WHERE NAME = 'package_name';
```

And in result I am getting package.pks file with everything from TEXT column.
Problem is that after every couple of rows it shows

```
TEXT
----------------------------------------------------------
```

How can I get rid of this?

Comment: Depends if you want to keep the first one, or want to get rid of them all. [And have you looked at the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_four.htm#sthref267)?

Answer (score 0):

you can solve this with

```
SQL> SET HEADING OFF
```